# CodeIgniter MVC best practice - Controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a `Google` controller class which has a method `distance()`. This uses Google's distance matrix to calculate the distance between two postcodes and returns the value.

Now I have another controller class called "Person". I want to call the `${Google}->distance()` method from within my `Person` class, to see how far this Person is away from a certain postcode.

How would I achieve this and am I going about this the right way.

Comment: rather than creating a controller, you could create a library for distance calculating script and call the library from whichever controller you want to...

Comment: Or you can simply create a custom helper

Comment: Thanks all, I am also new to CI, which is why I missed the whole libraries thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of the need to call another controller's method, you need to use [modular extensions](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) since CI itself does not support HMVC.

But in your case it's a bad design practice to place such logic in a controller, you need to make use of CI [libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/libraries.html) (recommended since `Google` is a utility class) or [models](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) (if the class abstracts database interactions).

Simply place your class in `application/libraries/Google.php` and in your `Person` controller:

```
// 1. Load library via CI's loader:
// You may want to autoload the library
// @see application/config/autoload.php
$this->load->library('google'); 

// 2. Use library:
// NOTE: If it's a static class you need to call it as:
// Google::distance($postcode1, $postcode2);
$distance = $this->google->distance($postcode1, $postcode2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you ask about is less about MVC but more about how objects and instances in PHP work.

A most straight forward usage would be:

```
$google = new Google();
$distance = $google->distance();
```

That is not high design, but the first step for you to get it to work. Later on you can decide if it isn't better to create the `Google` instance elsewhere, e.g. Codeigniter offers library loading mechanisms so you can hide away the details a little and can make it easier to access functionality.